# Single quotes in a path for a python script creates accented characters

Tags: keyboard, python

I've got a project with some Logic Circuit simulator and the place I study at gave us an auto-tester to test our logic boards. For some reason when the python code that runs said auto-tester writes the report for my logic board the following happens:

Writing a single quotation before an English letter gives it a grave accent, like Ç. Is there a way to disable that?

This messes up the file path, causing the auto-tester to not work.

I've tried manually changing the file path in the code but that doesn't appear to help, so removing the grave accent looks like my only option.

Thanks ahead to anyone trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows will do that if you have the Keyboard Language set to International English.

Set it to US or UK to avoid that, or add a spacebar after each occurrence.